# Jupyter, Python, %Debug: Setting breakpoint in module doesn't work

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook.

Considering the following code:

*cell1*

```
import pdbtest
```

*cell2*

```
%debug -b pdbtest.py:3
pdbtest.test(4,6)
```

*end of cell2*

`pdbtest.py` is a module located in the same folder as the notebook, containing:

```
def test(a,b):
    print("hello")
    a=a*2
    print("goodbye")
    b=b*2
```

Normally `the %debug` magic should set a breakpoint on the third line of the module. When run , this code returns:

```
Breakpoint 1 at /home/depot/notebooks/pdbtest.py:3
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
hello
goodbye
```

It seems the console has well understood the file and the location where the breakpoint should be, and give the return of the function. *However it doesn't stop on the breakpoint!*

Anyone has experienced the same?

Comment: I have the same problem via the IPython repl.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `%debug` magic command is only valid for the Python code that follows it in the same line, i.e., nothing.

If you want it to be valid for the whole cell, then you should use `%%debug`:

```
%%debug -b pdbtest.py:3
pdbtest.test(4,6)
```